# How can i prefixed to take input in an integer type array in c? When i use %[^\n] in case of string input

Tags: c

Hey i am a new bee in c programming....
I have faced the following problem...

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){
  char line[80];
  scanf("%[^\n]",line); /*here i say it is terminated when new line encounterd*/
  printf("%s",line);
}
```

This code work for taking string input in a line and also force scanf to take input with space...

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){
    char line[80];
    scanf(" %[ ABCD]",line); /*here i say when program encountered anything without blankspace, A,B,C,D it is terminated*/
    printf("%s",line);
}
```

here an another code which take only blank space and 'A','B','C','D'

if i want to do this job in case of integer type by using this what can i do?

Comment: You're able to do complex things with `scanf` but haven't seen `%d` yet?

Comment: i hope you do not get my problem ok let me clear...

Comment: i want to take input in a integer type array but want when get 9 as a input it is terminated to take input....is it possible by using the upper technique which i apply in case of string...?

Comment: The `%d` format spec will automatically discard *leading* whitespace but not the *following* whitespace. There are various ways of doing so. One of them is `scanf("%i%*c", &i);` which reads and throws away (because of the `*`) a single character, after reading the integer.

Comment: Another way would be to read a string with `fgets` and then apply `sscanf` to the string as `sscanf(line, "%i", &i);` You then simply forget the rest of the string.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
main(){
    char line[80];
    scanf(" %[ ABCD]",line); //here i fixed space and ABCD for the input if other character is encountered then the process of taking input is terminated//
    printf("%s",line);
}
if i want to follow this technique to take input in case of an integer type array that means suppose i want if 9 or 8 or any numeric value base on my choose are get on input the program is terminated as like this program on this comment .... is it possible?

Comment: Please don't ask detailed questions in comments. I understood your original question, and gave alternative ways to achieve something similar. If you want to use that method in your example, then read the number as a string first.

Comment: yap i understand!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
   int i;
   printf("Please enter a number: ");
   scanf("%d",&i);      /* Waits for input.    */
   printf("You entered %d\n",i);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry..... It wasn't my problem My problem was suppose i want to take integer input in an array as like as my first given code on my question post and want to terminate when i give 9 as a input how can i do this?

Comment: it also any numeric number in case of 9

Comment: then add an if-statement when i is 9 call return

Comment: yap get this point .... if i want to terminate my program for multiple numeric number then must i have to use if-else statement and it make my solution more complex so what i want to do this job as like [^\n] which i use in the first program for string input in string type array...Actually i want to know is it possible ?

Comment: just like it:#include<stdio.h>
main(){
    char line[80];
    scanf(" %[ ABCD]",line); /*here i say when program encountered anything without blankspace, A,B,C,D it is terminated*/
    printf("%s",line);
}